# Sparse Columns in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Do Oracle databases have something like SQL Server 2008 Sparse Columns?

Comment: It would be helpful to specify what features of the SQL Server `SPARSE` keyword you're hoping to replicate.  If you are most interested in the disk space savings, the answer is probably not but the way Oracle handles NULL values is pretty efficient already.  If you are most interested in using a sparse column for a filtered index, the answer is probably yes with a function-based index.  If you are most interested in solving some other problem, let us know what that problem is and there is a good chance there is another feature in Oracle you can use.

Comment: Justin, thanks for your comment. I´m have some information that is, well, sparce, meaning most of the columns on a given record are null. Today my representation of this uses a key/value table that is cumbersome and bad for performance.  I want move this to a Sparce table on SQL server. What would be a good way to do that in a Oracle. Short version: I want to save space and better performance and I want to have the cake too. Thanks. By the way, the cake is a lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in SQL server Sparse columns efficiently manage empty data in a database because they enable NULL data to consume no physical space.

i guess the equivalent in Oracle is Trailing Null 
where trailing null columns in a table consume zero bytes of storage.